# SXA Search append or hide QueryString

Tags: sxa

When using SXA Search box or facets in order to filter the search results, Query String is appended in the URL.

- Is there a way to hide query strings?
- How to append the Query strings?

Using SXA 1.6

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such way. SXA search renderings are using BackboneJS which by default is using parameters after URL `#` and there is no easy way to get rid of them or replace them to normal query parameters (instead of hash params).

We had a task in the backlog to replace hash params with query ones but it would require too much work and as for now, we are not planning to do this.